# Do I need to use _stdcall when I export functions to be used by other languages?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In order for my function be used by other language, do I have to use _stdcall to declare my functions in C++?

Comment: Note that on x64 there's no difference between `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`.

Comment: Explicitly stating the calling convention for the interface functions helps if the client has another setting for his projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be strictly *necessary*, but it's generally the path of least resistance. Just for example, if the other language happened to be C, you could probably use `_cdecl` or `_fastcall`. If you want to support arbitrary languages, though, `_stdcall` is the obvious choice.

Comment: @Jerry, what's the advantage of using _fastcall?

Comment: @user705414: There usually isn't one -- I certainly wasn't recommending it, only pointing out that it *could* work. In case it wasn't clear: I'd generally recommend using `_fastcall` (and that's what I'd normally do myself). And yes, you normally *do* need to do something to get _stdcall. You can mark it in the source code, or you can use the `/Gz` compiler flag, but the default is `_cdecl`.

Comment: if using _stdcall, can it be used by C language?

Comment: @user705414: Yes -- at least most C compilers know how to call _stdcall functions. The vast majority of the Win32 API uses _stdcall, so it's a little hard to imagine a Win32 compiler that couldn't use _stdcall functions.

Comment: @Jerry, "I'd generally recommend using _fastcall", I just want to know the reaosn behind this recommendation.

Comment: Oops -- that was a typo. I generally recommend using _stdcall for any purpose like this. I apologize.

Comment: @Jerry. got it. BTW, the member method is by default using __thiscall, is this same as __stdcall? Can this be used by other OO languages?

Comment: @user705414: _thiscall puts `this` in ECX, and pushes other args on the stack, so it's not quite like anything else. I don't know of another language that does exactly the same, but that could easily be just lack of awareness on my part.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend fastcall for DLLs; different compilers have different notions of what it means. Embarcadero puts the first three arguments in registers; Microsoft uses only two, and not the same as the first two Embarcadero uses, and remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack in the opposite order. Don't use thiscall, either, or else you end up like the ITextServices API, which only Microsoft C++ compilers can use without thunking headaches. User, please see Wikipedia for [X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: @Rob, __thiscall is the default one for member method. Can I changed it to __stdcall as well?

Comment: Certainly, @User. If you're exporting *classes* from your DLL, it won't make much difference, though, because only Microsoft C++ compilers can *consume* exported classes anyway. But if you're defining COM *interfaces* used by your DLL, then please use stdcall for those methods so that other compiler vendors and languages can use them.